# How does the telethon `events.NewMessage` work?

Tags: telethon

I am learning Telethon to develop a bot. I have learned that the `events.NewMessage` could filter some messages via `func` or for specific chats/channels.

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage(func=lambda e: e.is_private))
async def handler(event):
    pass  # code here
```

I am curious how it works, I am not sure if the following is correct or not.

The telethon library receives all the messages from the telegram server from the time it connected with the server, then filter messages by the pre-set rules? In this case, the telegram server actively sends all the chat/channel messages that the user joined.

Any corrections would be helpful.